# CASE WHEN "__" LIKE "__" ELSE "__" MySQL Error

Tags: mysql, sql, select, domo

I am trying to standardize campaign naming conventions in a dataset via MySQL. Please see the code below;

```
SELECT 
`Campaign`
FROM 
`cost_per_platform`
case when `Campaign` like '%brand%' then 'Brand'
else 'Other' end
```

This is run via DOMO.com MySQL function. I am provided with the following error;

> The database reported a syntax error: You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near 'case when `Campaign` like '%brand%'
>   then 'Brand' else 'Other' end' at line 5

Does anyone have a suggestion on a fix? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Shouldn't this `case` statement be before the `from` clause, e.g. `select case ... end from table`?

Comment: It's invalid syntax. `SELECT ... FROM table_name CASE WHEN ...` is not a valid syntax. MySQL was not expecting a `CASE` after your `FROM` table name. I understand you want to standardize the name, but what output are you expecting from the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the `case` expression in the `select` clause:

```
select
    campaign,
    case when campaign like '%brand%' then 'Brand' else 'Other' end as new_campaign
from cost_per_platform
```

This adds the second column to the resultset, called `new_campaign`, that represents the "standardized" value.

If you want an `update` query instead (that is, replace the existing value with the "standardized" value)

```
update cost_per_platform
set 
campaign = case when campaign like '%brand%' then 'Brand' else 'Other' end
```

Comment: That worked great! Thank you. If I want to add another value to include, that is, in addition to Brand, if I wanted to add another LIKE, THEN, ELSE statement, what would be the best way to do so?

Comment: @Nick: you can add more `when` branches, like: `case when campaign like '%brand%' then 'Brand' when campaign like '%foo%' then 'foo' else 'Other' end`

Answer (score 0):

Would

```
SELECT 
if(`Campaign` like '%brand%', 'Brand', 'Other' ) as Campaign
FROM 
`cost_per_platform`
```

be sufficient for your needs ?

Answer (score 0):

Your query would look lie

```
SELECT 
  case when `Campaign` like '%brand%' then 'Brand'
  else 'Other' end
FROM 
`cost_per_platform`
```